# Map or Copy in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I recently wrote an extension to replace a single item in an immutable array, and found two good approaches:

Copy:

```
extension Array
{
    func replacingItem(at index: Int, with item: Element) -> Array
    {
        precondition(index < self.count)
        var copy = self
        copy[index] = item
        return copy
    }
}
```

Map:

```
extension Array
{
    func replacingItem(at index: Int, with item: Element) -> Array
    {
        precondition(index < self.count)
        return self.enumerated().map { $0.offset == index ? item : $0.element }
    }
}
```

Is one of these two approaches better than the other? What are the differences in how each method is run?

Comment: I would suggest to go with the first one, since you are aware of the index, there is no need to iterate through the whole thing (`.map`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Copy**

makes a copy of the current array (`self`) in all and replaces the given element at given index (quasi `o(1)`).

**Map**

creates a new array and iterates over the current array (`self`). In each iteration it appends either the current element or the given element if the index matches the given index (quasi `o(n)`).

---

The difference is that ***Map*** is performing a repeat loop under the hood with a check for each item which is much more expensive than to copy the object instantly and update the desired item **once**, so ***Copy*** is the more efficient way.